# debug session doesn't work with debug gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I am making a personally developed application.
I have tried to debug with debug gem which became standard from rails 7, but (rdbg) does not work smoothly even if I enter debug session.　I don't know what is the cause. Please let me know if any advice.
My Gemfile as following.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.2', '>= 7.0.2.4'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'importmap-rails'
gem 'turbo-rails'
gem 'stimulus-rails'
gem 'tailwindcss-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'redis'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

gem 'sorcery'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'config'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'enum'
gem 'enum_help'
gem 'draper'
gem 'redis-actionpack'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'validates_email_format_of'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'solargraph'
  gem 'letter_opener_web'
end
```

I have put 'debugger' in conrtroller and enter debug session, terminal console will be the following screen.

[image]

My understanding is that it should be prompted (rdbg) and wait for debug commands.
However, no matter how long I wait, (rdbg) does not appear.
There is no response when I press n (next) command. (Sometimes it works, but it takes a lot of time and is completely useless.)
Can you give me some advice?

Comment: i have the exact same problem: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.
I changed the Rails version (7.0.2.4-> 7.0.3) and recreated the app, but the situation didn't change.

Comment: Same problem, when starting with "rails s"(without foreman gem) instead "./bin/dev/" it's works fine

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I've confirmed that it works normally if it is started with "rails s".

Comment: I had a similar issue few years ago using overmind which had the same problem as foreman. It seems that it is not as straight forward as is when you start the server using bn/dev or rails s. You need to connect to the debugging process. In terminal open a new window and from the same folder where your app is run: bundle exec rdbg -a

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? Not use "bin/dev"?

Comment: I don't use "bin/dev" and am using "rails s". In that case, you will also need to start a separate redis server locally (if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm a Mac user and you will need to adapt this advice/learning to you platform.**

If switching off of `foreman` isn't an issue then here is what I did; using `overmind` as a replacement:

1. Change your `bin/dev` file to this:

```
if ! command -v overmind &> /dev/null
  then
    echo "Installing overmind via homebrew..."
    brew install overmind 
  fi
  
  export PORT="${PORT:-3000}"
  overmind start -f Procfile.dev
```

Does the same as `foreman` but instead you are using `overmind` now. So run `bin/dev` in the terminal as you normally would.

2. While running `overmind` in your terminal, open another terminal and 'connect' to the overmind `web` process using this command: `overmind connect web`. It'll grab just the `web` service that is by default declared in your Rails 7.x `Procfile.dev` and give you access to the debugging process in the manner you are accustomed to in the past.

Example Procfile.dev based on mine:

```
web: bin/rails server # <== see how the dots connect: overmind connect **web**`
js: bun run build --watch
css: bun run build:css --watch
```

Of note:
This is **objectively** better if you find the `watch` noise in the aggregated logs a bit much then with this will allow you to see only the web logs separately.

Some additional resources for those inclined:

- [How Rails Procfile works with Foreman, Overwind + hive](https://railsnotes.xyz/blog/overmind-better-bin-dev-for-your-procfile-dev#overmind-basics--what-makes-overmind-a-better-bindev)
- [Another: How Rails Procfile works with Foreman, Overwind + hive](https://jasonfleetwoodboldt.com/courses/rails-7-crash-course/how-the-rails-procfile-works-foreman-overmind-hivemind/)
- [overmind](https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind)

Answer (score 0):

From [FVVID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823774/debug-session-doesnt-work-with-debug-gem#:%7E:text=%E2%80%93-,FVVID,-2%20days%20ago)’s comment, the cause seems to be that the server was started with "bin/dev" command.

My environment is "importmap + tailwindcss".
"tailwindcss" is not updated during debugging, so I can now use the debug gem by starting the server with the "rails s" command instead of "bin/dev".

Thanks to FVVID.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Overmind, here's what worked for me:

1. Open a new shell / terminal window
2. Atttach the debugger: (in my case I'm using ruby/debug):

```
rdbg --attach
```

And you're off to the races!